# Fullscreen WebView Android

Tags: android, webview

WebView in my app shows as window, but I want it be fullscreen! Here is screenshort of it:
[image: not fullscreen]

Here is my code:

```
public class DockViewerActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(mWebView);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");

        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.loading), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: Not working. Get the same result.

Comment: your activity is already full screen, make sure you're making your webview fill the width and height

Comment: Try this : 
    

    mWebView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Answer (score 4):

## XML

set the height and width to match_parent like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/conrainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent "
         android:layout_height="match_parent "/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Activity::

to remove the status bar you have to use:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

to remove titlebar,you have to use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

both of the above features you have to set before set your content view like below i am doing:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.base_screen);
}
```

## if you Create webView programtically then set the `height`, `width` to `match_parent` like:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 mWebView .setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and its done now!! #cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my codes to achieve full screen webview.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
            ...
    }
```

And XML Layout of this activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mains"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    ...
    <WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:visibility="visible"
/>
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```